# GCP API Gateway How to config 50 to 60 endpoints using API Gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-gateway

Have multiple API to be configured using API Gateway. But config file will be larger and more over it is not possible to configure each and every API in API Gateway. Is there any other ways are there for it ?. I am using cloud functions and clouds run endpoints.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no i didn't found anything upto now

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple API config files added in one API Gateway. Either you have multiple API Gateways and route them through a single Load Balancer or combine all the configs into one giant config file which goes into the gateway.